# limit of a series homework question

Tags: calculus, limits

I need some help with this question.

**The question:**

Prove or disprove the following statement:

If $$a_n\cdot a_{n+1} \rightarrow 0$$ and $a_n > 0$ for all $n$, then
$$a_n \rightarrow 0$$

**Solution attempt:**

The solution I was given disproves this statement using an example (which I understand):
$$a_n = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1\quad & {n\quad odd} \\ 
\frac{1}{n}\quad &  n \quad even
\end{matrix}\right.$$

but I don't understand what is wrong with this proof:

For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N$ so that for all $n\geq N$, $a_n\cdot a_{n+1} < \epsilon$. Therefore (because $a_n > 0$ for all $n$):

$$a_n<\frac{\epsilon}{a_{n+1}}<\epsilon$$

which prooves the statemant.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality $$\frac{\epsilon}{a_{n+1}}<\epsilon$$ is not true. In fact, that inequality is only true if $a_{n+1} > 1$, which is not true for the particular example you cite. In fact, the inequality is reversed for all even values of $n$.